# Vector addition, how can this vector be u-p?

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

[image]

How can this vector that is orthogonal to p be u-p? it does not even have the same direction as p. (p is the projection of u on p)

Comment: $u-p$ is the vector that you add to $p$ to get $u$. Visually, the vector labeled $u-p$ does indeed have this property. Why would you expect $u-p$ to have the same direction as $p$?

Comment: no I got confused with vector addition to represent another vector, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$d = u-p$ must fulfill:
\begin{align}
p + d &= u \iff \\
p + (u-p) &= u
\end{align}
and this it does.

Answer (score 1):

The projection is calculated as

$$
{\bf p} = ({\bf u}\cdot \hat{{\bf v}})\hat{{\bf v}}
$$

Now calculate

$$
{\bf p}\cdot ({\bf u} - {\bf p}) = {\bf p}\cdot {\bf u} - {\bf p}\cdot {\bf p} = ({\bf u}\cdot \hat{{\bf v}})({\bf u}\cdot \hat{{\bf v}}) - ({\bf u}\cdot \hat{{\bf v}})({\bf u}\cdot \hat{{\bf v}}) = 0
$$

The vectors are orthogonal!

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the vectors as instructions to walk a certain distance in a specified direction.

$p$ is walk east $4m$.

$u - p$ is walk north $3m$.

$u$ is walk approximately east north east $5m$.

Think of a $3, 4, 5$ triangle.  You can get from the bottom left by the $5$ side or the $3$ and $4$ sides in sequence.  The net effect is the same.